# Error in linear regression as function of independent variable

Tags: regression, linear-model, residuals, standard-error

I have some x and y data that are clearly correlated like this:

[image]

So we can predict y if we know x. We can also calculate the mean error in our prediction by taking the root mean square of the residuals. I have done this (and the value is 3.2). So we can predict y by knowing x, with an expected error of plus or minus 3.2.

This seems quite crude, as we can clearly predict y more precisely when x is very low (e.g. 10) as opposed to when it is high (e.g. 45). How can I produce an error estimate for the y prediction that is a function of x?

My regression must be forced through the origin, neither X nor Y can be negative.

Bonus appreciation if you can tell me how to do this in python!

Comment: It's not so clear that your prediction can be made more precise at low (or even high) values of $X,$ because you are not accounting for the fact that the scarcity of points at the extremes of the scatterplots should make you very uncertain about their error variances.  Having said that, the assumption that $Y$ is nonnegative implies ordinary least squares is not the right model.  There are many alternatives whose choice depends on what you know (or assume) about the conditional distributions of $Y.$  What can you tell us about them?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Each point represents a series (~100) of measurements of snow depth. Y is the standard deviation of the measurements, X is their mean. I have used the python numpy.linalg.lstsq package to do the regression.